# Initializing metadata and then update it from the background thread

Tags: java, cassandra

I am working on creating a scheduler which will connect to cassandra database and extract data from few tables and store it in few variables. Then from my main thread I will be using those variables by calling getters on them from `CassUtil` class. Basically, I will cache the result in memory and then from a single background thread I will keep updating those cache which runs every 15 mins.

Here is my code which makes connection to cassandra cluster and then load stuff into these variables `processMetadata`, `procMetadata` and `topicMetadata`. And then I call getters on these three variables from my main thread to get the data from it.

```
public class CassUtil {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getInstance(CassUtil.class);
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
  private List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata = new ArrayList<>();
  private List<String> topicMetadata = new ArrayList<>();

  private Session session;
  private Cluster cluster;

  private static class Holder {
    private static final CassUtil INSTANCE = new CassUtil();
  }

  public static CassUtil getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private CassUtil() {
    List<String> servers = TestUtils.HOSTNAMES;
    String username =
        TestUtils.loadCredentialFile().getProperty(TestUtils.USERNAME);
    String password =
        TestUtils.loadCredentialFile().getProperty(TestUtils.PASSWORD);

    PoolingOptions opts = new PoolingOptions();
    opts.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,
        opts.getCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL));

    Builder builder = Cluster.builder();
    cluster =
        builder
            .addContactPoints(servers.toArray(new String[servers.size()]))
            .withRetryPolicy(DowngradingConsistencyRetryPolicy.INSTANCE)
            .withPoolingOptions(opts)
            .withReconnectionPolicy(new ConstantReconnectionPolicy(100L))
            .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
                DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy
                    .builder()
                    .withLocalDc(
                        !TestUtils.isProduction() ? "DC2" : TestUtils.getCurrentLocation()
                            .get().name().toLowerCase()).build())
            .withCredentials(username, password).build();

    try {
      session = cluster.connect("testkeyspace");
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      Set<Host> allHosts = cluster.getMetadata().getAllHosts();
      for (Host host : allHosts) {
        sb.append("[");
        sb.append(host.getDatacenter());
        sb.append(host.getRack());
        sb.append(host.getAddress());
        sb.append("]");
      }
      LOGGER.logInfo("CONNECTED SUCCESSFULLY TO CASSANDRA CLUSTER: " + sb.toString());
    } catch (NoHostAvailableException ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= " + ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
  }

  // start a background thread which runs every 15 minutes
  public void startScheduleTask() {
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          processMetadata = processMetadata(true);
          topicMetadata = listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID);
          procMetadata = procMetadata();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
        }
      }
    }, 0, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
  }

  // called from main thread to initialize the metadata
  // and start the background thread
  public void initializeMetadata() {
    processMetadata = processMetadata(true);
    topicMetadata = listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID);
    procMetadata = procMetadata();
    startScheduleTask();
  }

  public List<String> listOfTopic(final String consumerName) {
    List<String> listOfTopics = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select topics from topic_metadata where id=1 and consumerName=?";
    try {
        // get data from cassandra
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex), ", Consumer Name= ",
          consumerName);
    }
    return listOfTopics;
  }

  public List<ProcessMetadata> processMetadata(final boolean flag) {
    List<ProcessMetadata> metadatas = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from process_metadata where id=1 and is_active=?";
    try {
        // get data from cassandra
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex), ", active= ", flag);
    }
    return metadatas;
  }

  public List<ProcMetadata> procMetadata() {
    List<ProcMetadata> metadatas = new ArrayList<>();
    String sql = "select * from schema where id=1";
    try {
        // get data from cassandra
    } catch (SchemaParseException ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("schema parsing error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      LOGGER.logError("error= ", ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(ex));
    }
    return metadatas;
  }

  public void shutdown() {
    LOGGER.logInfo("Shutting down the whole cassandra cluster");
    if (null != session) {
      session.close();
    }
    if (null != cluster) {
      cluster.close();
    }
  }

  public Session getSession() {
    if (session == null) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No connection initialized");
    }
    return session;
  }

  public Cluster getCluster() {
    return cluster;
  }

  public List<ProcessMetadata> getProcessMetadata() {
    return processMetadata;
  }

  public List<String> getTopicMetadata() {
    return topicMetadata;
  }

  public List<ProcMetadata> getProcMetadata() {
    return procMetadata;
  }

}
```

And here is my Initializer code which calls `initializeMetadata()` method to initialize stuff. I am using Spring here.

```
@Singleton
@DependencyInjectionInitializer
public class TestInitializer {

  public TestInitializer() {
    LOGGER.logInfo("Initializer called.");
    CassUtil.getInstance().initializeMetadata();
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void postInit() {
    LOGGER.logInfo("PostInit called");
    // doing some stuff
    // accessing those three variables by calling getter on them from CassUtil class
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void shutdown() {
    LOGGER.logInfo("Shutdown called");
    // doing some stuff
  }
}
```

I wanted to see if my `CassUtil` class can be improved in any way. My main idea is to access `processMetadata`, `procMetadata` and `topicMetadata` variables from main thread without calling cassandra every time and instead it should load data from cache which is getting updated every 15 mins. So, I need to have a background thread which runs every 15 minutes and extract data from cassandra tables and then populate these variables and then I can use these variables from main thread.

Is there any better way? I am using Java 7.

Comment: `CassUtil` is not spring component? If no, why? Do you have requirement why `CassUtil` should not be spring component?

Comment: It is just a CassandraUtil class which is a Singleton class where I am making connection to cassandra and getting stuff out from cassandra. Does it have to be Spring components? I will use this class to call getters for those three variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sugestions for your solution:**

I have few sugestions how I would improve your solution. BTW it's really good job what you have done.

**1, externalize sql queries**

```
String sql = "select * from schema where id=1";
```

In my opinion in the code there should be as least as possible hardcoded strings. When you will need to change table name from `schema` to `new_schema` you will need to recompile all the project - it's OK for one or two times but what about 20times? I would pull my hair out :).

**2, Method `shutdown` refactoring**

I would rather vote for:

```
 if (null != session || null != cluster) {
      session.close();
 }
```

**3, Constructor `CassUtil`**
has 40+ lines - I think you should break it to few methods. At least `cluster` is candidate for private method.

**4, rename method to follow JavaBeans syntax definition**

```
listOfTopic -> getTopics
processMetadata -> getProcessMetadata
...
```

---

**Tip #1:**

Since you are using spring I would think about making `CassUtil` as a spring managed bean. But if you are using CassUtil in non-spring components you don't have to read following:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    @Bean
    public CassUtil() {
        // you are able to delete Holder and make `CassUtil` public construcotr
        // by default @Bean is in scope singleton
        return new CassUtil();
    }
}
```

With that you are able to inject (`@Autowired private CassUtil cassandraUtil`) wherever you want (in spring component of course).

I would create new spring `@Component` like: `CassandraProcessor` and put here all `service` methods like `getters` and also `scheduled method` (dont forget to `@EnableScheduling`):

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate=900000)
public void startScheduleTask() {
        processMetadata = processMetadata(true);
        topicMetadata = listOfTopic(TestUtils.GROUP_ID);
        procMetadata = procMetadata();
}
```

This should be executed on the startup of spring application so I suppose you don't need `initializeMetadata` at all.

After implementing this approach when you will need to get `listOfTopic` you just `@Autowired private CassandraProcessor cassandraProcessor` and call `cassandraProcessor.listOfTopic()`.

---

**Tip #2:**

The next option is to use [**`ehcache`**](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) or similar cache manager with cacheloader and you wouldn't have to manage scheduling etc.